# Facebook Integration in iOS 5.0

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios5, xcode4.2

I have developed an iPhone Application in Xcode 4.2.1 (iOS5) with ARC(Automatic Reference Counting)... I have integrated Facebook by creating staticLibrary with new Facebook iOS SDK (downloaded from this link https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)... To integrate Facebook i had written the code in the tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/...

When i follow above link the complete Facebook is integrating into my application... But i want to write code(just by deleting the code in the above tutorial) to allow the user to login and post a wall and logout(login button, A Label/prompt to write wall , share button, logout button), when user click share i want to send an attachment(which can't be edited by the user) with that wall... i.e; My application should work as the Sample project in the tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app...

I want code to write in my ViewController.m file for the new sdk in the first link/ the sdk used in that tutorial(both r same)... If i follow raywenderlich tutorial completely i'm getting the error like..

[image]

Then What i have to do now to get the output like the project by raywenderlich (o/p: posting a wall with an attachment) with New iOS SDK... Please help me...

Thank u...

Comment: Since this tutorial posted facebook has changed their sdk to the newer version. Download and use new Facebook sdk.

Comment: From Where i Have to download new Facebook sdk... i followed this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/... in this we have the new Facebook sdk.. But i'm not getting the output what i want... Please let me know is there any link with new sdk..

Comment: For getting proper output you have do some changes in your code compatible to new SDK's. There are no other sdk facebook provide for this. The above link is correct one.

Comment: Yes, I want code to write in ViewController.m file to post a wall with an attachment... If i follow above link i am integrating the complete Facebook which i don't want...